# Installing Prestashop developer version

Tags: composer-php, prestashop

I wonder if anyone has experiencing installing Prestashop 1.7 dev version on Windows 10?  I cloned the developer vbersion of Prestashop from the official git repo and initiated the install.  The install asks me to run the command "php composer.phar install" so I did and get the following error when I do:

```
  Problem 1
    - composer/installers is locked to version v1.7.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - composer/installers v1.7.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match your constraint.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies to allow updates and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You are using a snapshot build of Composer 2, which some of your plugins seem to be incompatible with. Make sure you update your plugins or report an issue to them to ask them to support Composer 2. To work around this you can run Composer with --ignore-platform-reqs, but this will also ignore your PHP version and may result in bigger problems down the line.
```

I am running the latest version of composer on Windows 10 and am at a complete loss on how to proceed any further therefore any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? The given message shows a clear hint that you are **not** running the most recent stable version of Composer (which is 1.10.5), but a more recent development build

Comment: I'm running version 2.0 of composer which is the most recent version.   I've heard back from Prestashop and they tell me there dev build isn't yet compatible with composer 2 so I'll close this topic for now.

Comment: What makes you think that v2 of composer is released yet?

Comment: M y bad, I meant 1.10.5

Answer (score 0):

According to the Prestashop team their development build is not yet compatible with Composer 1.10.5 hence the errors I encountered.

Thanks.